# align tabularx header and cell/column with "itemize content" plus table borders are not connected

Tags: latex

I have the Tabularx structure as follows how can I align each column or cell based on my need particularly the cells or column with the itemized item. currently, itemized items are aligned to right and I want to be aligned to the center or left. how to align header to the center? also, the intersections on the corner are not connected!!!. what should I do?

Thank you in advanced

Document is as follow:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{3}{>{\compress}X|}}
        \caption{caption}
        \label{tab:table1lable}                             \\
        \toprule
        head1 & head2 & head3         \\            
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        %---------------------------------------------------------------%
        \caption{caption} \\  %\hfill(continued)
        \toprule
        head1 & head2 & head3 \\         
        \midrule
        \endhead
        %---------------------------------------------------------------%
        \multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continued on the next page}}
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        
        \hline
        A&B&C\\
        \hline
        col1\_content & 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item col2 list item1
            \item col2 list item2
        \end{itemize} &
         
        \begin{itemize}
            \item col3 list item1
            \item col3 list item2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

full latex package and preamble is below :

```
\documentclass[
%draft,
final,
paper=a4,
paper=portrait,
fontsize=12pt,
version=last,
twoside,
ngerman,
titlepage,
toc=listof,
toc=bibliography,
usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=4cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
%\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
%    
\usepackage{mathptmx}%
\usepackage{tabularx}    
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
% Fix for floats
\usepackage{scrhack}    
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage{xcolor}   
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs}   
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}    
\usepackage{hyperref}    
\usepackage{caption}
% Fehler mit nicht zentrierten Captions beheben
\captionsetup{width=2\textwidth}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{ifdraft}
\ifdraft{\let\ifxdraft\iftrue}{\let\ifxdraft\iffalse}

% Hurenkind und Schusterjunge
\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{code}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    commentstyle=\color{blue},
    extendedchars=true,
    frame=single,
    identifierstyle=,
    keepspaces=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{Sepia},
    language=C,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    stepnumber=1,
    stringstyle=\color{orange},
    tabsize=1,
    title=\lstname
}

\lstdefinestyle{text}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    extendedchars=true,
    frame=single,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=1,
    title=\lstname
}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

%

\usepackage{colortbl} % color table
\definecolor{maroon}{cmyk}{0,0.87,0.68,0.32}
\newcommand{\gray}{\rowcolor[gray]{.90}}

%
\usepackage{xargs}                      % Use more than one optional parameter in a new commands

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
% caption for tabular x
\usepackage{siunitx} % SI Unit
\usepackage{marginnote} % add margin note 
%\marginnote{This is a margin note using the geometry package, set at 3cm vertical offset to the line it is typeseted.}[3cm]

\usepackage{tabularx} % table



\title{Business Intelligence to Support an Indicator-Based Waste Incineration Process}
\author{Mohammadjavad Ranji}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\let\ThesisTitle\@title
\let\ThesisDate\@date
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{3}{>{\compress}X|}}
        \caption{caption}
        \label{tab:table1lable}                             \\
        \toprule
        head1 & head2 & head3         \\            
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        %---------------------------------------------------------------%
        \caption{caption} \\  %\hfill(continued)
        \toprule
        head1 & head2 & head3 \\         
        \midrule
        \endhead
        %---------------------------------------------------------------%
        \multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continued on the next page}}
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        
        \hline
        A&B&C\\
        \hline
        col1\_content & 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item col2 list item1
            \item col2 list item2
        \end{itemize} &
         
        \begin{itemize}
            \item col3 list item1
            \item col3 list item2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "the intersections on the corner are not connected!!!" That's a feature of the booktabs package - you should not use vertical lines in tables!!!!

Comment: Please don't load the same package multiple times. You load some of them, not once, not twice, but THREE times

Answer (score 1):

- The best way to avoid gaps in the line surrounding table cells is not to use vertical lines. Have a look at the user guide of the booktabs package for more information on how to get a professional looking table
- as you are using the `enumitem` package, you can set the `leftmargin` to avoid extra horizontal space at the left side of the cell

---

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tabularx} % table


\begin{document}
    
    
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{3}{>{\compress}X}@{}}
        \caption{caption}
        \label{tab:table1lable}                             \\
        \toprule
        head1 & head2 & head3         \\     
        \cmidrule(r){1-1}   \cmidrule(lr){2-2}   \cmidrule(l){3-3}     
        \endfirsthead
        %---------------------------------------------------------------%
        \caption{caption} \\  %\hfill(continued)
        \toprule
        head1 & head2 & head3 \\         
        \cmidrule(r){1-1}   \cmidrule(lr){2-2}   \cmidrule(l){3-3}     
        \endhead
        %---------------------------------------------------------------%
        \multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continued on the next page}}
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        
        
        A&B&C\\
        \addlinespace
        
        col1\_content & 
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item col2 list item1
            \item col2 list item2
        \end{itemize} &
         
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item col3 list item1
            \item col3 list item2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```